# jQuery: Admin view example

Tags: jquery

```
            success: function(data){
            $('#rightContent').prepend('<h2>' + data.information['myPosition'] + '</h2>');![enter image description here][1]
            $.each(data.information.Firstname, function(key, value){
                $('#rightContent').append('<span>' + value + '</span>');
            });
        }
```

[image]

I need to put it on table or any good looking view. For firstname, middlename, lastname. Just a sample would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for... (*press the run code snippet to see it*)

```js
// this object is the object you showed above
var information = { 
  Firstname: ["Super","Bat"], 
  Lastname: ["Man","Woman"], 
  Middlename: ["Freakin","Na Na Na Na"] 
};

// hold an array for the rows we will need
// also creater the header row
var rows = [];
var $header = $("<tr/>");

// create the table
var $table = $("<table/>");

// for each item in your information object
// you may need to limit this to first/last/middle
for( item in information ) {
  
  // Store the item, I couldnt think of a proper name
  var level = information[item];
  var levelName = item;
  
  // append the object name to the header
  $header.append("<td>"+ levelName +"</td>");
  
  // now append all the items in the array for this item
  for( item in level ) {
    
    // because this loops, we only want to set the row once,
    // so set it to itself first if it's empty.
    rows[item] = rows[item] || $("<tr/>");
    rows[item].append("<td>" + level[item] + "</td>");

  }

}

// now see how many items were added to the
// rows array, and add them all to the table
for( item in rows ) {
  $table.append( rows[item] );
}

// insert the header at the start.
$table.prepend( $header );

// add your table to the body ( change this as needed );
$("body").append( $table );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and here's a JSFiddle because I don't really feel that Stackoverflow code runner lends to editing well.. http://jsfiddle.net/81r8cq19/

Comment: That's what exactly I'm looking for. I've been on headache for a couple of days just to figure out how to make a table like that. I could loop it using $.each(obj, function(key, value){}). Thank you @simey.me

Comment: Please explain further rows[item] = rows[item] || $("<tr/>"); I need to know this also though it's working well. Thanks.

Comment: Javascript is a loose/falsey language; so I exploit that by saying `set rows[item] to its own value, but if its value is falsey (undefined) then set it to a new <tr>` ... and the reason I do this is so that all the `<td>` with the same index go into the same row... You could remove `= rows[item] || ` quickly to see what would happen... it would overwrite itself for every item... it's a bit of a lazy/clever way around a recursive issue. :)